# Passing an drawable image from 1st activity to 2nd does not work (only from 2nd to 1ast does) Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

`enter code here`This is my First Activity::> I need:
1) select an option 
2) click send an image (from drawable) should go  to the second activity but it does not only from 2nd to 1st works fine all my xml and manifest files are correct (I double checked)

```
package com.example.damianlopez.myassignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button toBob;
    private ImageView burgerImage;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupChoice;
    private RadioButton radBurger;
    private RadioButton radScare;
    private RadioButton radSick;
    private final int MY_SELECTION = 111;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       try {
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //get radio Buttons
           //radioGroupChoice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radGroupChoice);
           radBurger = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radBurger);
           radScare = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radScare);
           radSick = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radSick);


           //display app icon
           ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
           ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
           ab.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

           //getting Intent
           Intent getIntent = getIntent();
           Bundle myBundle2 = getIntent.getExtras();
           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, getIntent);

           //
       }catch(Exception e ){

    }

    }//End onCreate()
    public void onClickButton(View v){
        try {
            //get radio gruop id's
            radioGroupChoice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radGroupChoice);

            int mySelection = radioGroupChoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if(radioGroupChoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                //creating new Intent
                Intent msgToBob = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main22Activity.class);
                Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
                myBundle.putInt("imageChoice", mySelection);
                msgToBob.putExtras(myBundle);
                startActivityForResult(msgToBob, MY_SELECTION);
            }

        }catch(Exception e ){

        }

    }//End of onClick()
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent myData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, myData);
        Log.i("OnActivityResult() call", "***********");
        radioGroupChoice = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radGroupChoice);
        int selected = radioGroupChoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        //get Images
        burgerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pumpkin_burger);
        if(radioGroupChoice.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_SELECTION: {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        if (radBurger.isChecked()) {
                            burgerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pumpkin_burger);
                        } else if (radScare.isChecked()) {
                            burgerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pumpkin_scared);
                        } else if (radSick.isChecked()) {
                            burgerImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.pumpkin_sick);
                        };
                    }
                break;
                }//end case
            }//end switch
        }//end else if

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();``

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

This is my Second Activity===>

```
package com.example.damianlopez.myassignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RadioGroup radioGroupChoice2;
    private RadioButton radBurger;
    private RadioButton radScare;
    private RadioButton radSick;
    private Button toAlice;
    private ImageView currentImage;
    private ImageView scareImage;
    private ImageView sickImage;
    private final int MY_SELECTION2 = 222;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main22);

        //display app icon
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        //Buttons
        radioGroupChoice2 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radGroupChoice);
        //toAlice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sndToAlice);

        //get the intent called
        Intent myLocalIntent = getIntent();

        Bundle myBundle = myLocalIntent.getExtras();
        myLocalIntent.putExtras(myBundle);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myLocalIntent);


    }
    public void onClickButton2(View v){

        try {
            radioGroupChoice2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radGroupChoice);
            if (radioGroupChoice2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make a selection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent myIntent2 = new Intent();
                Bundle myBundle2 = new Bundle();
                int myImage = radioGroupChoice2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                myBundle2.putInt("selectedImage", myImage);
                myIntent2.putExtras(myBundle2);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, myIntent2);

            }
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }
        finish();
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main22, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: how do you know it's working from 2 to 1 activity what I am looking for there is no operation with myData in first activity inside onActivityResult

Comment: because on my second activity UI I selected an image the click send message it displays that image  back to my 1st activity